# JavaScript full screen relative to browser window, not monitor

Tags: javascript, web, fullscreen, responsive

I have made following function in JS:

```
function fullScreen(element) {
    if (element.requestFullScreen) {
        element.requestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }

    link = document.getElementById("slideshow");
    link.removeAttribute("onclick");
    link.setAttribute("onclick", "cancelFullScreen()");
    }
```

This function lets me view the content full screen relative to the monitor. I can not find any information on how to make a full-screen relative to the browser window.

To be more specific, what I want concrete is to have the rest of the web site "blacked out" (like with opacity) while the picture is full screen inside of the browser (with or preferably without UI)

Comment: Because of being a school task this can not be completed using jQuery

Comment: Off the top of my head, you'd could set the relevant element to absolute positioning, top and left 0, with a high z index and height/width 100% (or possibly right and bottom 0 as well, I forget, give it a try)

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to use the window.open() with passing the image src

```
<img src="five.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli" onclick="window.open(this.src)">
```

Comment: This only opens a blank browser window

Comment: if you want to open in same window  use "window.open(this.src, '_self')"

Comment: This doesn't do anything

Comment: It will open in the same window

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open image as popup you can use Model image [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp)